# ASP.NET MVC Razor form validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a for loop in my page:

```
 @foreach (var manufacturer in Model.Manufacturers)
{
    <div class="tab-pane form-horizontal" id="@manufacturer.LanguageCode">
        <input type="hidden" name="Manufacturers[@i].LanguageId" value="@manufacturer.LanguageId"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input name="Manufacturers[@i].Name" type="text" value="@(manufacturer.Name)" class="form-control name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have an idea as to how i can create `jquery` code with validation rules:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("name", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2
});
```

Is it possible to use `@ Html.ValidationMessageFor (model => model.Name, "") or @ Html.ValidationMessage.`

How best way to validate this form with `jQuery` validation?

Comment: Firstly, you need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` for binding to work correctly - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Manufacturers.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manufacturers[i].LanguageId)... }` What is it that your trying to validate? (and whats important is server side validation - client side validation is just a nice bonus that anyone can override)

Comment: You can set up validation in your model classes, and if you create your controllers and views from those models the client side validation will be automatically set up for you. Also you can use fluent validation in your models to create more complex server/client validation rules. Check out the asp.net site for some articles